# Best packages to improve formatting of LaTex document

Tags: fonts, formatting, header-footer, fancyhdr, article

### Best packages to improve formatting of LaTex document

---

**Context**

---

There are many packages designed to improve the styling of a LaTex document, making it look different and clearer from the typical slabs of default text.

> For example, the FancyHDR package allows customization of footer lines and headers, thus making it a useful package for improving the overall formatting of the page.

---

**Question**

---

So my question - what else is out there? What are the most useful packages for customizing a LaTex document format? i.e. toggling headers, footers, fonts, spacing, etc. Are there others as useful as FancyHDR?

Comment: Personally I dislike the `fancyhdr` package preferring the `memoir` class facilities. What suits one person does not necessarily suit another.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX is (by design) built to create exceptional typeset text out-of-the-box. It distills literally hundreds of years of typesetting experience and the some into a (more or less) easy to use package.

Sure, it is also extremely flexible, in that anybody can come and change the way things look with a package. Unless the package writer is knowledgeable and has good taste (both scarce commodities), the result will often be less than stellar.

The above said, the KOMA series of packages allow much flexibility *in the range that makes sense*. Personally, for longer texts I'm partial to the `memoir` package, which can also be tweaked a lot (there are lots of example formats for chapter titles in MemoirChapterStyles on CTAN).